# Add a page with RewriteURL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to add a page with file **recipes.php** to the existing WordPress web site, **sea-horse.org**. I need to access **recipes.php** in the format given in **sea-horse.org/recipes**.

How do I edit my existing WordPress **.htaccess** file:

```
# BEGIN A2 Optimized 
# DO NOT REMOVE 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On RewriteRule wp-content/plugins/a2-optimized/resource/(.*) wp-  content/a2-resource.php?resource=$1 [L] 
</IfModule> 

ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml 
# END 

A2 Optimized 

# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] RewriteCond %   {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 

# END WordPress –
```

Comment: Yes, existing website not running .

Comment: # BEGIN A2 Optimized
# DO NOT REMOVE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule wp-content/plugins/a2-optimized/resource/(.*) wp-content/a2-resource.php?resource=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml
# END A2 Optimized






# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /recipes.php [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   </IfModule>

Comment: Fixed grammar; improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the .htaccess file from within the Wordpress Admin. You'll need to edit it using an IDE like Aptana, or download it using an FTP client like FileZilla, make changes, and upload back to your server.

Comment: # BEGIN A2 Optimized
# DO NOT REMOVE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule wp-content/plugins/a2-optimized/resource/(.*) wp-content/a2-resource.php?resource=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml
# END A2 Optimized
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
How can i modify this. because i have not much knowledge in .htaccess file edit .

Comment: Try looking up Pretty Permalinks for Wordpress. It sounds like what you are trying to achieve can be done without directly editing htaccess.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 0):

You can just go to your theme folder and then copy the `page.php`in the `recipes.php` then at the top of the `recipes.php` just add the following

```
/* Template Name: Recipes Page */
```

After that just go to the backend area and create a new page. Name the page in the slug that you want to use in this case `recipes` and from the sidebar in the new page area select the Recipes Page as page template. After that you can modify the code with the one you need on that page.

Comment: I just  a crated page recipes.php  to the existing wordpress webiste (sea-horse.org). Need to access  recipes.php in this url format sea-horse.org/recipes .  recipes.php page not associated with wordpress. this is a seperate file i had created in core php.

Comment: Then you can just create simple folder in the root of the WP name it `recipes` and inside create index.php with the content of `recipes.php`. This will give you the structure you need